# How To Go Live in Facebook without Going Public

Tags: facebook

I am working on an app for a company to pull in Facebook Insights data for a data warehouse.  The app itself is a simple .NET client/REST API that works fine but is limited by the amount of data we can pull at a time because we are in development mode.  I've looked into going into production mode, but Facebook wants a privacy policy and a number of other steps that leads me to believe the app will become publicly available.  How do I go to production mode and still keep this private?  Is it possible?

Comment: Public doesn’t mean everyone will automatically find and start using your app. Got any _specific_ concerns, what kind of “bad things” do you expect to happen, just because it is “public”?

Comment: The specific concern is that I don't want it visible to the public.  This is meant as an internal application only and I don't want any confusion that someone might associate the company with producing Facebook apps and 'freak out' over privacy concerns.